# How do I timer log in Java and analyse the results?

Tags: java, logging, time, logback

My application server has slow paths that need analysis. I want to measure time and find out the slowest path, fix it, and measure again.

Google return results for timers that schedule threads and tasks, which is not what I want.

*I use logback and can put log-statements in different methods*. Each line has a timestamp. This data is logged into a separate logger. The duration of the action is the difference between 2 timestamps.

*Is there a way to analyse this timer log data, without manual evaluation of the duration?* A tool? A methology? A best practice that I should use?

I want to put timer log data through my application and then quickly find slow actions that need my attention. Application servers are also running in customer environments, a timer logger is an easy way to analyse their performance.

Answer (score 0):

Tather than add timing logging to your code, why not use a "profiler". there are plenty out there but my favourite is [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/cpu_stat.jsp). You can download a 15-day trial evaluation but you have to pay beyond that (well, unless they grant you an extension.

Check out the CPU profling features (in the above link) and especially profiling of "hot spots". As it happens, it's also very useful in memory profiling through it's application of "object generations" to keep watch for long-lived objects. I also like the "probes" feature for analysing resource usage (e.g. Connections being opened and properly closed).

For the sake of balance, other profile tools are [jprofiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) and jprobe (not sure of suitable download site).

Comment: I will test your suggestion. I also updated my question, that this application server is also running in customer environments. In this way, a timer-log is easy to manipulate.

Comment: Hmmm ok. You wouldn't attach to a live app server with a profiler. You would normally use a load-test tool (LoadRunner or the free jmeter) to create user load and test it locally.

Answer (score 0):

You could also have a look at the VisualVM profiler (https://visualvm.java.net), which comes with the JDK. It's quite easy to use and does the job properly, and (if you ask me) is better to do than writing log messages.